# How to get graphs to render in Mermaid + Jekyll / GitLab Pages?

Tags: gitlab, jekyll, mermaid, gitlab-pages

I have a GitLab Pages project and trying to render graphs using Mermaid.

In the head.html I included this line ...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ '/assets/js/mermaid/mermaid.js' | absolute_url }}"></script>
```

And then placed the `mermaid.js` file in the `myproj/assets/js/mermaid` directory.

And in my *.md file I have:

````
```mermaid
graph TD;
  A-->B;
  A-->C;
  A-->D;
  A-->D;
```
````

Yet, I get no renderings.

I'm trying to use the method in the link below which seems to support only using JS, and therefore should work with GitLab pages, but I haven't found the file called `mermaid.full.min.js` in the repos, so ... maybe it's not supported, or has since changed up?

http://kkpattern.github.io/2015/05/15/Embed-Chart-in-Jekyll.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're using Jekyll, so if you don't mind to use a plugin, I hope the below can help you do it easier.

> jekyll-spaceship -  A Jekyll plugin to provide powerful supports for table, mathjax, plantuml, mermaid, youtube, emoji, vimeo, dailymotion, etc.

https://github.com/jeffreytse/jekyll-spaceship

There are two ways to create a diagram in your Jekyll blog page:

````
```mermaid!
pie title Pets adopted by volunteers
  "Dogs" : 386
  "Cats" : 85
  "Rats" : 35
```
````

or

```
@startmermaid
pie title Pets adopted by volunteers
  "Dogs" : 386
  "Cats" : 85
  "Rats" : 35
@endmermaid
```

Code above would be parsed as:

[image]

Comment: Excellent, works locally. Just took a bit of work. Much thanks.

Comment: Though this does help to render diagrams locally, it doesn't work with Github/GitLab pages as I'd need to render them locally and push the static files which is what I'd like to not have to do.